# Displaying multiple image from SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I need to display multiple images from a database table and bind it to a repeater, how do I go about doing it?

This is my current code, but I have no idea on how to proceed to display images

Below is my method to load data to the repeater:

```
public void loadNoofNewJobsCompany()
{
        DateTime lastlogged = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["LastLoginstaff"]);

        string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Job ";
        sqlStr += "WHERE ";
        sqlStr += "UpdatedDateCmpRep <= @loggedin";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loggedin", lastlogged);

        try
        {
            cnn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            Label2.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();

            PagedDataSource pgdsc = new PagedDataSource();
            pgdsc.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

            repeater1.DataSource = pgdsc;
            repeater1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cnn != null)
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="boxgrid caption">
            <%--<img src="../../img/google.png"  style="text-align:center"/>--%>
            <div class="cover boxcaption">
               <p>
                   <a href='../Job/ViewJobDetail.aspx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "JobID")%>' class="headerlink">
                   <%# getTitle(Eval("JobName").ToString()) %>
                   </a>
               </p>
               <p>
                   Salary Range:
                   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "JobSalaryRange")%>
               </p>
               ... (more stuff - not relevant here) .....
            </div>
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying images in gridview we need to create a Handler to read binary data from database.

[here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html) is good example of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the images are stored in the database.
Write `.ashx(Http handler)` to display the image.
You can render the image using Response Header in the .ashx file directly from the database and use that .ashx file as follow in your repeater,the images will get displayed.

```
<img src="displayImage.ashx?id=111"  style="text-align:center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

one more good example to look at 
[Display Images from database in ASP.NET GridView using HttpHandler](http://technico.qnownow.com/display-images-from-database-in-asp-net-gridview-using-httphandler)